# MTKView display HDR10 CIImage

Tags: ios, metal, core-image, ciimage, mtkview

I need to display CVPixelBuffers in HDR10 (*kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr10BiPlanarVideoRange* / BT2020 PQ color space) using MTKView. I have the following code to display but it produces distorted images, and I can not be sure if it is displaying 10 bit colors or it is clamping colors. Also whether bgra10_xr or bgra10_xr_srgb should be the right choice of colorPixelFormat and the difference between the two.

```
class CIImageView: MTKView {

    var image: CIImage? {
       didSet {
          self.draw()
      }
     }

   var originalImageExtent: CGRect = CGRect.zero 

   var scale: CGFloat {
       return max(self.frame.width / originalImageExtent.width, self.frame.height / originalImageExtent.height)
   } 


   func update() {
      guard let img = image, destRect.size.width <=    img.extent.size.width && destRect.size.height <=   img.extent.size.height else {
          return
       }
    
      self.draw()
   }

let context: CIContext
let commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue

convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
    let device = MetalCamera.metalDevice
    self.init(frame: frame, device: device)
    colorPixelFormat = .bgra10_xr_srgb
}

override init(frame frameRect: CGRect, device: MTLDevice?) {
    guard let device = device else {
        fatalError("Can't use Metal")
    }
    
    
    guard let cmdQueue = device.makeCommandQueue(maxCommandBufferCount: 5) else {
        fatalError("Can't make Command Queue")
    }
    
    commandQueue = cmdQueue
    
    context = CIContext(mtlDevice: device, options: [CIContextOption.cacheIntermediates: false])
    
    super.init(frame: frameRect, device: device)
    
    self.framebufferOnly = false
    self.enableSetNeedsDisplay = false
    self.isPaused = true
    self.clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    
    guard let image = self.image else {
        return
    }
    
    let dRect = destRect
    
    let drawImage: CIImage
    
    if dRect == image.extent {
        drawImage = image
    } else {
        let scale = max(dRect.height / image.extent.height, dRect.width / image.extent.width)
        drawImage = image.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
    }
    
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBufferWithUnretainedReferences()
    guard let texture = self.currentDrawable?.texture else {
        return
    }
    
    let colorSpace = drawImage.colorSpace ?? CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    
    context.render(drawImage, to: texture, commandBuffer: commandBuffer, bounds: dRect, colorSpace: colorSpace)
    
    commandBuffer?.present(self.currentDrawable!)
    commandBuffer?.commit()
}

private var destRect: CGRect {
    
    let scale: CGFloat
    if UIScreen.main.scale == 3 {
        // BUG?
        scale = 2.0 * (2.0 / UIScreen.main.scale) * 2
    } else {
        scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
    let destRect = self.bounds.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
    
    return destRect
 }


func displayPixelBuffer(_ pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, flip:FlipDirection) {
    self.image = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer)
}
```

Edit: I tried the suggestion of setting colorSpace manually but the colors are washed out.

[image]

Here is the screenshot from the same scene on iPhone that uses AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

[image]

Comment: Can you please try using this color space instead: `CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.itur_2100_PQ)` (in `context.render(…)`)

Comment: Do I have to explicitly specify colorSpace, wouldn't drawImage.colorSpace already have the right color space instead?

Comment: A `CIImage` only has a `colorSpace` when it is directly loaded from a source with a color space. But you are (potentially) applying transformations to it, so it would lose the color space information of the source.

Comment: Let me try and get back to you

Comment: The colors seem to be washed out. I will update the question with sample images

Comment: I updated the code with pictures

Comment: FYI, I am using bgra10_xr_srgb color space here

Comment: Changing it back to bgra_xr improves colors a bit but nothing close to original HDR content.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this answer from the developers of this framework on the [apple forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/664861):

> CAMetalLayer.wantsExtendedDynamicRangeContent is only available on
> macOS. Metal does not expose a way to display HDR content on iOS
> devices. HDR can only be done with videos and images.
>
> By setting the CAMetalLayer.pixelFormat to on of the XR formats (like
> MTLPixelFormatBGR10_XR_sRGB), Metal does provide a way to get some
> extra headroom for better tone mapped HDR effects than what standard
> sRGB. Although this is not true HDR like HDR10 or Dolby Vision it does
> improve the effect.

---

> Also whether bgra10_xr or bgra10_xr_srgb should be the right choice of
> colorPixelFormat and the difference between the two.

To display true **HDR** content you should use `MTLPixelFormatRGBA16Float` pixel format.